# Can I introduce species that don't have carryable seeds to new areas?

Tags: waking-mars

Some of the more interesting species (Phyta, Larians, Ledon Zoa) don't have seeds that you can put in your inventory and introduce somewhere else. Is it possible to introduce such a species to a location where it is not already present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Of those three species, an area may only contain the ones provided initially.

Even if you frighten a Phyta to the "entrance" to an adjacent area, they will treat it as a wall. The same applies for Ledon Seeds.

Comment: I haven't tested what happens if you wipe out all Phyta from an area, if you are stuck without them, or if the game will spawn in a new one if you run out.

Comment: I lost all of the Phyta in an area and they have not re-spawned. I'm not able to increase the biomass in that area anymore.